# "Skyscrapers are of various shapes" vs. "skyscrapers are various shapes": Preposition Deletion

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositions

> - Skyscrapers are of various shapes.
> - Skyscrapers are various shapes.

Why do we use *of* in the sentence above?

Is there any difference in meaning between the two sentences?

Comment: Related, [Roses are red, bananas are yellow](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4306/roses-are-red-apples-are-green).

Comment: Thank you Elberich. I see your point and I think that this is more of an ESL question.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider, the original title **of** the meta question you posted is: *Roses are red, apples are green*. I think it would be more helpful to guide the OP to the actual [ELL site](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) rather than a meta post.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider: How is a question concerning the parameters of licence in ellipsis related to primary level English?

Comment: @Edwin, first of EL&U is for linguists and etymologists, and none of them wish to read these kind of questions, furthermore the lack of 'of' in that sentence is not an 'ellipsis', but it is a plain error at all.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider The missing "of" in sentence No 2 is not actually an error. Both sentences are grammatical, please read the three answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ellipsis occurs in many constructions in English.

Words considered non-vital are often omitted.

Here, the post-modifying adjectival prepositional phrase 'of various shapes' is seen to be ellipted by the omission of the preposition:

> 2) Skyscrapers are of various shapes.
>
> 1) Skyscrapers are various shapes.

The use of a preposition is optional in the following sentences.

Prepositions are often omitted from temporal adverbials / whatever temporal 'additives' go with *be*:

> We were here (in) the winter before last.
>
> She visited us (on) the day before yesterday.
>
> She was here (in) the previous December.
>
> They waited (for) two hours for the bus to come.

I'd say it doesn't make sense for 'two hours' in the elided last example to be analysed as a direct object. There is a name for such DO-lookalikes, noun groups functioning adverbially and/or  locatively / directionally / temporally: adverbial objectives.

The Rohirrim went *north*. Is John *home* yet? *Today* I came *a different way*. Elms stood *either side of the street*. Let's go *some place*. He lives *next door*.

Similarly, though the corresponding adjectival usage is, I feel, very rare, I'd class 'various shapes' in OP's elided example as an adjectival rather than a DO:

> Skyscrapers are typically rectangular, stepped, or subtly rounded. Yes,
>
> Skyscrapers are rectangular, stepped, or subtly rounded.
>
> Skyscrapers are various shapes.

Though the 'adjectival objective' (don't quote me! - at least for a while) is very uncommon, the few examples that do exist seem to be increasing in popularity, as this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+different+shapes%2Care+of+different+shapes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20different%20shapes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20of%20different%20shapes%3B%2Cc0) seems to indicate. On the first page of Google hits for "are different shapes", 5 are obviously this usage as opposed to 2 which are obviously other constructions (following existential 'there' . . .).

In some cases, the 'of', complete, version, would sound ridiculous:

> The Shard and the Gherkin are not the same shape / size.

but obviously 'the same shape' / 'the same size' can't be taken as DOs.

I suppose that there is the slight possibility of confusion:

> The pyramids and kites on pages 2 and 3 are different shapes.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Skyscrapers are various shapes
>
> 2) Skyscrapers are **of** various shapes

Version 1 ambiguously implies that *skyscrapers* is a subset of *shapes*, as in "squares, circles, triangles, X-skycrapers, and Y-skyscrapers, are all shapes."

Version 2 implies that skyscrapers **resemble** various shapes, not that skyscrapers **are** shapes.

---

As an example, the following sentence uses "of" to form an [adjective clause](http://faculty.washington.edu/marynell/grammar/ADJCL.html).

> That skyscraper of a cylindrical shape is the tallest I have ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

1) Skyscrapers are of various shapes: using "of" in this sentence indicates that skyscrapers can take any shape. They can either be built in rectangle,square,pyramid,etc.

2) Skyscrapers are various shapes: Here not using "of" completely changes the meaning. This sentence says that skyscrapers are a part of different shapes. This sentence simply means just like ellipse,circle,pentagon are different shapes, skyscraper is also a shape.