# Compound adverb — "kick-start a party soccer style"

Tags: grammar, adverbs, compounds

I have asked this question in ELL site, but there were not much reply, and so I decided to ask the same question here. Though I will change the question a little bit to exactly what I need more and to stop you from repeating the same answer that I already got from ELL site.

Here is the [link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26037/why-there-is-a-missing-in?noredirect=1#comment48434_26037) for my question in ELL

> Times Life tells you how to kick-start a party **soccer style** as the FIFA World Cup 2014, in Brazil, gets underway.
>   — *The Times of India*

I understand the meaning of this sentence, but I was curious to know that why there was no ***in*** before the bold part of the quoted sentence.

One answer in ELL site suggests that *soccer style* is by itself acting as an adverb. Hence there is no need for any preposition. Fine with me, but I am wondering how to decide which compound words I will use as an adverb and which I won't.

Comment: I can just see the party participants flopping to the ground and writhing in simulated agony whenever they get brushed by someone...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding strict rules for when you can drop the preposition... I'm afraid there are none. Most of the time, though, both will be correct; as Edwin mentioned, it's a matter of register - in other words, how formally you're speaking. Dropping the preposition makes it more informal. The reason *not* dropping the preposition in the example you gave sounds cheesy is that it's a contrast between the *very* informal "soccer style" and the formal register.

I think that in most cases, either form (preposition and prepositionless) would be valid as long as they are right for the context (formal or informal respectively). I'm sure there are exceptions, but like so much of the English language, there are no rules I can give you for finding them; experience is unfortunately the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: in both versions

> Times Life tells you how to kick-start a party in soccer style ...
>
> Times Life tells you how to kick-start a party soccer style ...

the prepositional phrase or reduced prepositional phrase is an adverbial (modifying, ie adding to the detail conveyed by, the verb [kick-start]).

If a part of speech is felt necessary for the prepositionless 'soccer style', it *must* be (compound) adverb.

The prepositionless version is more punchy (in fact, the prepositional phrase version sounds rather cheesy in this example).

Comment: Thanks for replying, but how to decide which words can be used as adverbs like this one, and hence will go prepositionless?

Comment: That would probably require a doctoral thesis. Or three. As is the case with a lot of areas of English, simplifying rules seem thin on the ground. Note that this preposition-drop is used in a chatty, modern register. And for an adverbial. cf He put it a nice way / in a nice way.

Comment: Any docs discussing about this one?

Comment: You might find the discussion in [this thread](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141624/skyscrapers-are-of-various-shapes-vs-skyscrapers-are-various-shapes) useful, though it's not comprehensive.

Comment: The only advice I can give is to listen for tone. "Kick-start a party soccer style" has three words or phrases that give away the tone -- "kick-start", "party", and "soccer style" -- fresh, hip, energetic, informal, a little bit wild.