# Ignoring me the whole day or for the whole day

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Is “ignoring me the whole day” grammatically correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Skyscrapers are of various shapes" vs. "skyscrapers are various shapes": Preposition Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141624/skyscrapers-are-of-various-shapes-vs-skyscrapers-are-various-shapes-prepos) '... Prepositions are often omitted from temporal adverbials ... They waited (for) two hours for the bus to come....' Here, I'd say 'They ignored me _all day_' is more idiomatic.

Comment: So basically in this case, prepositions don’t play significant role?

Comment: There are many situations where prepositions may be (and often are) deleted (We will stay [for] a week.) There are many places where they must be retained (We will stay for the foreseeable future).

Comment: "They ignored me (for) **a** whole day."  would be idiomatic. Here is a link to an ELL question that is the exact same one you are asking: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/122906/118547