# two objects are/are of/have the same length

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

Is one form of this sense more correct than another?

Two objects are the same length.
Two objects are of the same length.
Two objects have the same length.

Comment: Does your research hint at a difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Skyscrapers are of various shapes" vs. "skyscrapers are various shapes": Preposition Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141624/skyscrapers-are-of-various-shapes-vs-skyscrapers-are-various-shapes-prepos) It's not an absolutely exact duplicate, but coupled with 'basic question' and 'lack of research', means the question is not suitable for ELU. (Bottom line: all 3 are grammatical and used, and are probably listed in order of increasing formality.)