# "The exam sheet should only be used to write answers (on)"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, omissibility

Do I need the prepositions in these sentences?

> The exam sheet should only be used to write answers (on).

> The blanks should only be used to write answers (in).

> The equipment should only be used to test the operation of the system (with).

I feel either way works but it seems to me it is more common to omit the preposition. The versions with prepositions sound better to me though. Are there situations where the prepositions can't be omitted? What rules govern this?

Comment: There has been a question on the same subject yesterday; it might answer your question: a complement must follow prepositions except in some cases; You should find that the 3 sentences do not fit the requirements.  Here is the link: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/331528/118547 .

Comment: @LPH CoGEL would have been better writing 'a complement must immediately follow a preposition except in some cases'.  This question is about preposition deletion, not postponement.

Comment: Perhaps a reasonable introduction to this difficult question is given at [skyscrapers-are-of  various shapes vs skyscrapers are various shapes – preposition deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141624/skyscrapers-are-of-various-shapes-vs-skyscrapers-are-various-shapes-prepos). There are other questions addressing preposition deletion, but perhaps no succinct overview.

Comment: This is a consequence of the verb _use_ with a purpose infinitive. Unwind the passive to get _One should only use the exam sheet to write questions (on)_, which has the same optionality. _She used the exam sheet to wipe her nose (with)_, likewise. The purpose infinitive will often sport a transitivizing preposition, but if the object isn't there any more, who needs the preposition? So it's variable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There seems no other way than treating the use of the prepositions in theses sentences as cases of deferment. It seems these sentences are on the model of the obligatory deferment (infinitive clause with thematization of the prepositional complement). "Exam sheets" is the prepositional complement: "You write answers _on exam sheets_"; in "The exam sheet should only be used to write answers (on).", the exam sheets is being thematized. According to the rule of obligatory use of the preposition,  "on" is necessary.  (CoGEL ex., same structure, "He is impossible to work with.")

Comment: @LPH 'The equipment should only be used to test the operation of the system' is grammatical and arguably synonymous. Other examples OP could give are  'This scooter is impossible to ride [on].' 'He filled the form [in].' Preposition deletion. Seen also in say 'Who did the Chinese fight [against] in 1894-5? 'the cat brushed [against] my leg' ....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Fill in" is a so-called phrasal verb, so it 's out of the question. "The cat brushed [against] my leg" is also a case of plain deletion.  "fight [against] " is an undecidable case as "fight _against_" (intransitive, contend in war, battle, single combat)) is a quasi-synonym of "fight" (transitive, engage in battle, duel, etc.). "Ride" is again an undecidable case (intransitive "ride _on_" is synonymous with transitive "ride").  It remains the first case, and that one is not clear to me; it sounds correct, and it  sounds better without the preposition; yet "with" should be used.

Comment: @LPH Labeling 'fight against' as what is essentially a spelling variant of 'fight' ducks the issue. **Why** is preposition deletion, or if you prefer apparent preposition-deletion, allowed in this and _some_ other cases? There is probably a streamlining (some would say bastardisation) going on.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In my opinion, usage is king. Why would you hardly ever think of saying something like "he has no place to go to" but would  consider unthinkable the possibility of saying "the boy they gave it is not him"? Usage, mere usage…

Comment: None of those prepositions is needed and please note two things:

First that all three example seem contrived. Are they your compositions, or where do they come from?

Further, their use of 'only' falls into the same trap afflicting almost every English speaker, however native or erudite. (If that seems pedantic, so is the Question.)

Almost all speakers almost always put 'only' in the wrong place, usually too early.

This is a trivial example yet 'The exam sheet should be used only to write answers' while necessarily being many things other than 'used only for…'